# Codeigniter search?

Tags: codeigniter

This project is something like a social networking site built on codeigniter.

Here my default controller is MyController.php (which loads the login page)
and say my domain is aravind.com

In my application each user will have a unique id.
and what my requirement is, the particular page of the user should get opened when 
the unique_id of the user is given immedetily after the domain name.
ie, `aravind.com/123` should open the user page whose unique id is 123.

I know this can be acheived by placing a controller and a function in between the 
domain and the unique_id, (like : `aravind.com/Search_class/search_func/123`).
But by doing so the url of the particular user becomes lengthy which is not acceptable.
So I require a logic to sort this issue.

Note:
I have other classes and folders in my controller package, SO the required soln should be 
wise enough to diferentiate my classes and folders in the controller package with the UniqueID.
So for differentiating I can say like the classes and folder name will be of continuous String 
Where UniqueID starts with an underscore (`_`).

The same thing is done in facebook, like if we type `facebook.com/aravind.pillai.983`, it will open my account,
where as if the url goes like `facebook.com/settings` it will open the settings page for 
the user who have an active session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `route["404_override"]` to one of your custom class (say `Search.php`).
So wheneven a user tries to enter with an invalid url it will be redirected to Search.php.

Here using `$this->uri->segment(1)` you will get the value of the first uri segment.

You can write a logic there to identify whether the user entered a valid unique_id or not.

Now you got the uri value in one class (Search.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use routing where you can set every routes you want. In `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` file add this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Search_class/search_func/$1';
```

You should read [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) about routing and check other [examples](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples).

Also, pay attention that application will always check for `Search_class/search_func/$1` in first URI segment so you need to put this rule at the end of `routes.php` file. Before that rule you need to set other rules like:

```
$route['about'] = 'pages_c/show/about';
$route['contact'] = 'pages_c/show/contact';
// then after all declared routes, you can set wild card placeholder
$route['(:any)'] = 'Search_class/search_func/$1';
```